# What do Bootstrap Toggable tabs do vs standard Bootstrap stabs?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I want a page which presents multiple tabs in a row. When I click on the tab or tab drop down, I want to present a new page of data or functionality. That new page will have the same tabs on top.

I do not understand the purpose of the Bootstrap toggable tabs vs the standard tabs. I see that they are driven by javascript. But What do the toggable tabs really do which the standard ones do not ?  I do not need fade etc.

Bs standard tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Bs toggable tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard tabs are meant more for general navigation of sorts.
    You can click one, go to that page, and that page will have the same
    tabs but the one you're on is now set to active. It's more of a basic implementation of the navbar. Clicking a tab is meant to take the user to a completely different page.

The togglable tabs are for when you want to present information on
    the same page by presenting sectioned off areas independently based on which tab was clicked. Something like features for something you're looking to sell, for
    example.

As the documentation for togglable tabs indicates, the features to make them togglable are meant to extend featuers of the standard nav/tabs.